# How to access start addresses of a Content Source programatically?

Tags: sharepoint-2007

How can we get a list of start addresses added in a Sharepoint content source programatically ? The code which need to achieve this will be running on different server than where sharepoint is installed so i am looking for a solution where we can query sharepoint database to get this list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Never** query the sharepoint database directly. Even a simple select statement an cause a read lock, potentially creating havoc in your farm.

By using the database directly you are **NO LONGER SUPPORTED**, meaning that if it does go belly up and you call microsoft for support, they'll send someone from consulting ($$$$) or ask you to go back to the last known good configuration (i.e. a backup of your sharepoint databases from before the point you started accessing the database directly...)

Create a web service that uses the sharepoint object model to get this list, then deploy it to the sharepoint machine, then have your external app use that service.